# Color reference in <item>-Tag, inside <layer-list>

Tags: android, reference, colors

**I have a question about using references in a `layer-list` `drawable`.**

I want to use a custom button in my app, made of a `layer-list`.

- That is the final drawable `btn.xml` for the button, made of a `selector`:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>
</selector>
```

- The pressed-state-drawable `btn_pressed` looks like that:

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="?custom_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>
</layer-list>
```

The essential part is the line, where i declare the color to be a reference to `custom_color`, that i define as follows.

- attrs.xml:

```xml
<resources>
    <attr name="custom_color" format="reference|color" />
</resources>
```

- themes.xml:

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="custom_color">#ff33b5e5</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Eclipse gives me no errors at all, and it compiles just fine.
But when i start the application on my ICS Nexus S, or the Emulator (no matter what version), it crashes. Logcat points the following out:

> 03-23 14:33:38.832: E/AndroidRuntime(636): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/btn.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020006
>
> [...]
>
> 03-23 14:33:38.832: E/AndroidRuntime(636): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/btn_pressed.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020009

If I comment out, the `shape`-element in the `layer-list`, or set the color hard-coded, everything works. So there seems to be a problem referencing attributes in a layer-list.

**So, does anyone know a solution to this problem? I want to change colors in that layer-list, depending on the theme, that my application is using.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems like this is a bug that wasn't looked at until Android L.
More details on the Android Issue Tracker: [Issue 26251](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251)

It should be fixed in Android L, but at least testing with the Android L Preview in the Emulator it doesn't seem to work completely, yet. At least it won't crash the app, but instead of showing the correct color, it just gives me transparency (#00ffffff). Maybe this isn't the case on the devices and/or once Android L stable is released.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:color="@color/custom_color"`